# how to convert images in a directory to TFRecords

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a directory that consisted of captcha images, each image has the same name with the number on captcha. The maximum length of the captchas is 5. And I wanted to convert these images into TFRecords. To do so, I am using following functions;

```
def decode_label(label):
    one_hot_label = np.zeros([5, 10])
    index = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], map(int, list(label))]
    one_hot_label[index] = 1.0
    return one_hot_label.astype(np.uint8)



def bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))



def convert_to(dir, name, path):
    filenames = map(lambda filename: os.path.join(dir, filename), os.listdir(dir))
    tfrecords_name = os.path.join(path, name + ".tfrecords")
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecords_name)
    for filename in filenames:
        image = imread(filename)
        label = decode_label(re.findall("_(.*?)\.", filename)[0])
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={'label': bytes_feature(label.tostring()),
                                                                       'image': bytes_feature(image.tostring())}))
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
    print("successfully convert data to tfrecords!")
```

However, I am getting the following error because of the line

```
label = decode_label(re.findall("_(.*?)\.", filename)[0])
```

> IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression `_(.*?)\.` imposes filenames in the `dir` directory to be named in a certain way.

```
<name>_<label>.<ext>

ex: 
captcha1_12345.png
captcha2_67890.png
```

It seems that some of your captcha's filenames do not respect this convention.

Comment: yeah you are right. its trying to find names such as "something_1243.png" so I reproduced my dataset according to it but now its saying IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: I guess this error comes from `decode_label`. because `<label>` part in some filenames is not in 5 DIGITS format.

Comment: opps :( is there any way to fix that?

Comment: try to replace your third line with this. `index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].extend(map(int, list(label)))`. if it does not work, rename your files so the `<label>` part will be 5 digit string.

Answer (score 0):

Index error is because your re.findall is returning no valid results, yet you are trying to do listobj[0] .... try and split out your regex and see why it's failing.

As an aside, a list comprehension is a bit easier to read than a lambda in passed to a map:

```
[ os.path.join(dir, filename) for filename in os.listdir(dir) ]
```

vs

```
map(lambda filename: os.path.join(dir, filename), os.listdir(dir))
```

If your filename is /somedir/somedire2/12345.png and you want 12345:

```
os.path.splitext( os.path.basename(path) )[0]
```

If you want to use regex instead, you can do:

```
#p is your full path
>> re.search(r"/(\d+)\.png",p).group(0)
'/12345.png'
>>> re.search(r"/(\d+)\.png",p).group(1)
'12345'
```

per your sample filename:

```
>>> p = "something_1243.png"
>>> re.search(r"(\d+)\.png$",p)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103749198>
>>> re.search(r"(\d+)\.png$",p).group(1)
'1243'
```

can't speak to any numpy errors, though if it expects an integer, you can see above that you have a string, so you'll need to cast your result

```
int(stringval)
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. Just one more question. what kind of results it should has to return? I am not an expert on regex, I am just trying to follow a tutorial. what should be the parameter of decode_label function?

Comment: give me a sample file name, and what you want to scoop out, I'll help you on your regex

Comment: if captcha is 4596, so the captcha name is 4596.png

Comment: I tried both of them but its saying AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: please paste a full sample of a path you're using

Comment: its trying to find names such as "something_1243.png" so I reproduced my dataset according to it but now its saying IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: tried to cast it but it says TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable